# How to enable mysql condition only if it passes particular date

Tags: php, mysql

Here I need to check in my database if current date is reached then i have to execute coding otherwise it has to be skipped

```
function list_hotel_default($country,$city,$location,$fromdate,$todate,$roomtype,$adults,$child_no)
{   
  $condition="country='$country' AND city='$city' AND location='$location'  AND     show2web='1' AND expiry_date is greater than current date";                              
  $active_hotel_get_qry =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  hoteldetails WHERE ".$condition);
}
```

if else then it should not execute

How to do this ?

Comment: Building your query by concatenating strings which are probably user input are vulnerable for SQL injection. So please escape your input or use something like the PHP PDO extension which does that for you.

Comment: See here: http://google.com/search?q=PHP+PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to check it with only date value then you can use

```
function list_hotel_default($country,$city,$location,$fromdate,$todate,$roomtype,$adults,$child_no)
{

  $condition="country='$country' AND city='$city' AND location='$location'  AND     show2web='1' AND expiry_date > CURDATE()"; 

  $active_hotel_get_qry =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  hoteldetails WHERE ".$condition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQLs inbuit date functions - specifically the [now](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function which returns the current time and date:

```
$condition="country='$country' AND city='$city' AND location='$location'  
AND     show2web='1' AND expiry_date > now()";
```

This is assuming that the `expiry_date` is actually a date or datetime field.